# How to movie all directory files to other directory from GULP

Tags: javascript, gulp

I need to move all directory file into other directory

```
gulp.task('move', function () {
    gulp.src([
        './ng4/dist/**'
    ], { base: './' })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./server/public/'));
});
```

I am trying like this.

My folder structure is :

> ng4 -> dist
>
> server -> public
>
> gulpfile.js

Answer (score 1):

This will work in your case

```
 gulp.task('move', function () {
       return gulp.src(["./ng4/dist/**/*.*"])      
           .pipe(gulp.dest("./server/public"));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
  return gulp.src(['somewhere/*.wtf'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/fonts'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/fonts'));
});
```

This is what I use to copy over some fonts. My folders:

```
-somewhere
-dev
-build
gulpfile.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below it might help you

```
gulp.task("tsscripts", function() {
gulp.src([
        'core-js/client/*.js',
        'systemjs/dist/*.js',
        'reflect-metadata/*.js',
        'rxjs/**',
        'zone.js/dist/*.js',
        '@angular/**/bundles/*.js',            
        'bootstrap/dist/js/*.js'
], {
    cwd: "node_modules/**"
})
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./libs"));
});
```